# Wrong errorcode when using JSON parser

Tags: php

I'm having trouble finding the error in my .php script.

I use an android app sending post requests in order to register a user including a unique device id and email.

When sending the data my api checks if the email or device id already exist so you can't register twice.

When registering the first time, everything works. When i try to register again with the same email it works aswell (getting the correct error). But if I use a different email (but the same device id) I get a wrong error code.

Here is the PHP-Code:

```
else if ($tag == 'register') {
    // Request type is Register new user
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $devid = $_POST['devid'];

    // check if user already exists
    if ($db->CheckUser($email)) {
        // user already exists
        $response["error"] = 2;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already exists";
        echo json_encode($response);}


    else if ($db->CheckDevice($devid)) {
            // Device already exists
            $response["error"] = 3;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Device already exists";
            echo json_encode($response);}
    else {
        // store user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password, $devid);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["devid"] = $user["devid"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);} 
        else {
           // user failed to store
           $response["error"] = 1;
           $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registration";
           echo json_encode($response);}
    }
}
```

Check Functions:

```
public function CheckUser($email) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        return true;} 
    else {
        // user not existed
        return false;}
}


public function CheckDevice($devid) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT devid from users WHERE devid = '$devid'");
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        return false;
    }
}
```

Store Function:

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password, $devid) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, devid, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', '$devid', NOW())");
    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        // get user details 
        $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
        // return user details
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm sending

I should get this error:

```
$response["error"] = 3;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Device already exists";
```

But i am getting this one:

```
$response["error"] = 1;
           $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registration";
```

Somehow when calling the `CheckDevice` Function it seems to return `false` although when I manually use `SELECT devid from users WHERE devid = '$devid'` in phpMyAdmin I get a `true`.

Then he fails to store because the device id must be unique and gives me the error (thats the only plausible explanation).

Comment: You are very vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should definitely fix that.

Comment: That is a lot of code posted there and without actually seeing your database it is difficult to see where yo are actually having a problem.  Have you tried debugging at all?  Throw in some `var_dump()` calls at critical spots in the code execution path and see if you are actually get what you are expecting.  This will help you narrow down your problems quickly.

Comment: I know, but thats not my problem right now. I will deal with that once I have the basic script done. This code is far from beeing released :)

Comment: I also think it odd in your `storeUser` function that you would need to query the database to get all the information on the user that you just inserted. I can see getting the insert id, but why waste another DB call to get information you already have at your disposal?

Comment: I used this code to create the database...nothing special so far.

`create table users(
   uid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   unique_id varchar(23) not null unique,
   name varchar(50) not null,
   email varchar(100) not null unique,
   encrypted_password varchar(80) not null,
   salt varchar(10) not null,
   devid varchar(13) not null unique,
   created_at datetime,
   updated_at datetime null
);`

Thanks for the tip though...I'm quite new to this so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some `echo $devid` in your CheckDevice method to see if your android device is really sending same id.

Maybe you got error somewhere (maybe you are not sending anything when you try to register as second user from same device id).

I think that this is yours problem (your android app).

Comment: Thank you, I found the error...should have thought of that before!

Answer (score 0):

I found my error!

The device id is 15 chars long, the table length was 13.

Thank you for your help, I feel like an idiot now :)

Comment: I feel all the time like that :) np